# Routing in Laravel is not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am using laravel 5.0

I am trying to route the following. But it is not working

```
Route::post('accesscontrols/permissions', 'AccescontrolsController@permission');
```

I don't know what error in this.

It does not access `permissions` function in `AccesscontrolsController`

I have a function in `AccesscontrolsController`

```
public function permission()
{
    $roles = DB::table('roles')->get();
    $permissions = DB::table('permissions')->get();
    return view('accesscontrols.permission', compact('roles', 'permissions'));
}
```

What I have did wrong?

Comment: What error it returns? Can you share your other route code? so that we can understand its not conflicting with other!

Comment: It shows empty page...

Comment: Your other routes works perfectly?

Comment: Maybe DB problems? Instead of returning the view, just return $roles and then $permissions and check if there's any info there

Comment: You don't write `Route::post` in laravel 5, use post(). Is your debug on in .env file?

Comment: @GauravDave in Laravel5, `Route::post` should not be problem [HTTP Routing - Laravel 5](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#basic-routing)

Comment: @ArifulHaque True, but if you're using laravel 5, then why use old function.

Comment: @GauravDave your argument is correction, If L5, no need to use old function.. but as I said if developer like to use, it should not be any problem and I believe in this problem, how route is used is not the problem.

Comment: We need more info. Can you provide the class declaration of your controller?

Comment: Can you give more details about the response? (You can use the "network inspector" of the web-browser to get that)

Comment: Used View not View::make

Comment: try `Route::any('accesscontrols/permissions', 'AccescontrolsController@permission');`

to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route declaration should be made in `app/Http/routes.php`.

Also, make sure that your controller is within the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace and that it extends `App\Http\Controllers\Controller`.

Ex:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function permission()
    {
        ...
```

---

Also, if you whish to test it in the browser (by typing "*accesscontrols/permissions*" in the address bar), you route should answer to the `GET` verb. Try to declare it using `Route::get(` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a view in your method and you are not working with any POST data, which is strange. Are you sure you want POST request and not GET?